# Apache - VirtualHost y puerto 8080

Tags: apache

Instalé wamp en windows 10, el puerto 80 está ocupado debo usar otro. Ejemplo 8080
Además creo un virtualhost ejemplo localserver.dev.

En httpd.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *:8080
    <VirtualHost *:8080>  
        DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/ 
        ServerName localserver.dev 
    </VirtualHost>
```

en esta publicación
en: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
   127.0.0.1        localhost
   127.0.0.1        localserver.dev
```

Anteriormente entraba al servidor con: localserver.dev

Ahora debo colocar: localserver.dev:8080

Hay algo que pueda hacer para no tener que colocar el número del puerto despues del nombre del servidor. Ósea para entrar como antes.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

La unica opcion es escuchando HTTP por el 80 o HTTPS 443.

Una opcion es cambiar el puerto de la otra aplicacion para liberar el 80 y redirigir segun contexto desde el apache mediante proxypass/proxypassreverse al nuevo puerto.

De esta manera podrias mantener los dos servicios por el 80 y acceder sin poner el puerto en la URL