# Apache vs Tomcat: Ocultar puerto en mi URL

Tags: apache, tomcat, puertos

Hola actualmente mi servidor corre un Apache junto con Tomcat. Soy un poco nuevo en esto, lo que quiero en realidad es ocultar o quitar el puerto en mis páginas web alojadas en el servidor. O sea actualmente esta como: **`dominio:8080`** y quiero que salga: **`dominio.com`**. Divagando por la web, me encuentro que  Apache corre en puerto 80 y Tomcat en 8080 por eso sale el puerto. Leí que una forma de solucionar estos es configurando un proxy. Lo hice de la siguiente manera: Agregué esta línea en mi archivo `httpd.conf` en mi Apache

```
ProxyPass / http://dominio.com:8080/
```

Funciona y todo pero al parecer solo si escribo la URL. Si busco mi pagina en Google por ejemplo, sale de nuevo con el puerto 8080 :(. ¿Cual seria el siguiente paso o que me falta por configurar?

Muchas gracias

PD: conector  de mi puerto 8080 de mi Tomcat:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: Duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11584/apache-virtualhost-y-puerto-8080?rq=1

Comment: Gracias Juan pero el problema es que al buscar mi pagina me redirecciona con el puerto 8080 y no quiero eso. Como dije: _Si busco mi pagina en Google por ejemplo, sale de nuevon con el puerto 8080_

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que entiendo, tu pagina en su totalidad funciona correctamente.

Si el problema es el cache de Google, no te preocupes por eso, con el tiempo será refrescado.

Si quieres puedes solicitar a Google que vuelva a indexar tus paginas, para eso te recomiendo leer lo siguiente:

## **Solicitar que Google vuelva a rastrear e indexar las URL**

1. Solicita una **exploración** (o exploración y procesamiento) de una URL con la herramienta [Explorar como Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch), o selecciona una exploración reciente de la tabla que cumpla con los requisitos anteriores. Comprueba que la página se muestre correctamente en la exploración, ya que si la herramienta de exploración no puede acceder a la página o esta no se muestra completamente, es posible que no se clasifique correctamente o que Google no pueda rastrearla.
2. Haz clic en **Solicitar indexación** junto a la exploración en la tabla del historial de exploración. Si la función de solicitud no aparece junto a la exploración, significa que esta no cumple los requisitos anteriores.

3.Selecciona si quieres rastrear solo esta URL o si también quieres rastrear sus enlaces directos:

- Selecciona **Rastrear solo esta URL** para enviar la URL seleccionada a Google para que la vuelva a rastrear. *Con este método puedes enviar hasta 500 URL concretas en un periodo de 30 días.*
- Selecciona **Rastrear esta URL y sus enlaces directos** para enviar la URL junto con el resto de páginas a las que dirige directamente la URL para volver a rastrearlas. *Puedes enviar hasta 10 solicitudes de este tipo en un periodo de 30 días.*

4.Haz clic en **Enviar** para añadir tu solicitud a la cola.

5.**No se garantiza que se vuelva a rastrear la URL ni que se haga de forma inmediata**. Habitualmente se tarda varios días en aceptar una solicitud. Ten en cuenta también que no podemos garantizar que Google indexe todos los cambios realizados, ya que para actualizar el contenido indexado depende de un algoritmo complejo.

Espero te sea de ayuda!

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/61360)

Comment: Muy bien, entiendo. Agregué el texto de referencia que indica como hacerlo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Debes de tener en cuenta

1. Si Apache Web Server y Tomcat están en el mismo servidor el puerto 8080 no debería estar expuesto fuera del servidor, si están en servidores independientes, deberías permitir la conexión únicamente desde la IP donde se encuentra Apache Web Server, ambas cosas se deben lograr con el firewall del sistema, es así como el proxy será el que se encargue de obtener el sitio web correcto sólo con el acceso a la URL por el puerto 80.
2. Solicitar una nueva indexación al motor de Google.
3. Paciencia, la indexación toma su tiempo para ver los cambios sin embargo al no estar expuesto el puerto el motor de indexado de Google sólo puede encontrar tu sitio web por el puerto 80.